# Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has already been installed on this computer

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, .net-framework-version

So I installed Visual Studio 2017 and decided to get it working before uninstalling 2013 and 2015. So done that and was prepared for there to be some issues after doing so. One problem was that .NET Framework 4.5 got uninstalled so I downloaded [.NET Framework 4.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30653) and tried to installed but got the message *"Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has already been installed on this computer."*

Is there a way to install it? Its required for a project I am working on with a team and cannot migrate it right now (plus I don't really have the authority to make that decision).

Just to reiterate the target framework is 4.5 and that unfortunately will not change in the foreseeable future.

Comment: due to not being able to afford to much time after some research and trying a few things with no luck... I am going to uninstall Visual Studio 2017 and all .NET frameworks ahead of 4.5 and then install 4.5 before installing VS2017 again. Will let you guys know if this works out, but also interested if anyone has come across this and had a way to fix it. Would be great to have a proper solution on this question thread in case someone else comes across it or it happens again in the future with later versions.

Comment: VS2017 ships with .NET Framework 4.6.x or 4.7 (based on the update level). So 4.5 would be replaced. If you do want to keep using only 4.5, you have to give up VS2017.

Comment: Can't be the case because when I hadn't uninstalled 2015 yesterday project was running fine targeting 4.5 in VS2017. but moment I uninstalled 2015 today and it must have removed 4.5 then it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-install the 4.5 targeting pack not the framework itself to fix your issue.

You can find it in the individual components section of the VS2017 installer.
[image]

Comment: Just went to modify --> individual components and it looks exactly like yours. After reinstalling 2017 4.5 appears under the target framework dropdown now though and am not getting the error I was getting when trying to load the project so the reinstall must've worked. Would have been nice to have seen if modifying the installation would have worked (I reckon it would of though).